Anime where kid has monster servants
I remember starting to watch this anime series on Netflix. Can't remember when I watched it, but was less than five years ago. I could not find the show on Netflix or by my Googling.
The main character is a kid (living in a mansion?) who has a large number of monster servants (I think they have a more casual master-servant kind of relationship, not dictatory) The kid is young.
I think that one of the monsters was female, and looked human enough to go to school with the kid. A class mate trying making friends with the monster, but the monster was interested in her master only (this was used as a comedy effect, eg the class mate does something nice to get her attention, but she shrugs it off, and goes and talks to her master instead.)
I remember little bits from episodes: one where human classmates come over, and the monsters have to hide from them.
(Think the reason is that the outside world doesn't know of the existence of monsters.)
Another where they were battling another monster army. The other side had a big wolf I think. I also think that the leader of they other side sacrificed their army if monsters for more power or something (The wolf fled & stood on a building)
The number of monsters the kid controlled was not a very regular number (eg not 100 or 1000 for example), but it was at least a hundred, I'm pretty sure. I think the series had this number as a part of its title.

It's 'Nura - Rise of the Yokai Clan' / 'Nurarihyon no Mago'.

From Wikipedia :

Rikuo Nura is 3/4 human and 1/4 yōkai, in which he has a human form in the day but transforms into his yōkai form at night. He lives in a house full of yōkai along with his yōkai grandfather. Trying to escape his fate, he does good deeds in order to avoid becoming a yōkai, despite his grandfather's wish that Rikuo succeed him as the Third Head of the Nura Clan. Rikuo is different because he helps humans. He eventually comes to terms with his yōkai blood and decides to take up the position of the Third Head of the Nura Clan. Multiple factions aim to stop him or usurp his position, and he must gather friends and allies, a new Hyakki Yakō under his banner of "Fear".


Could it be Monster Musume?  
From IMDB:  

In a world where humans co-exist with fantasy beings, a young man must share a flat with a bevy of beastly beauties.  

From Wikipedia:  

The story of Monster Musume revolves around Kimihito Kurusu, a Japanese student whose life is thrown into turmoil after accidentally becoming involved with the "Interspecies Cultural Exchange" program.
Creatures, known as "liminals," have become a part of human society, living with ordinary families like foreign exchange students and au-pair visitors, but with other duties and restrictions.


This is not the anime, but good guess.
